# Linux kernel function

Tags: c, linux, kernel

```
static int do_wait_thread(struct wait_opts *wo, struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    struct task_struct *p;

    list_for_each_entry(p, &tsk->children, sibling) {
        int ret = wait_consider_task(wo, 0, p);

        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In which cases kernel use `do_wait_thread` function ?

Comment: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/exit.c#L1501

Comment: Mention explicitly that this is part of kernel

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I tried to find answer in book "Understanding the Linux Kernel"

Comment: I need an answer very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using site http://elixir.free-electrons.com, you can see where is used [`do_wait_thread`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/ident/do_wait_thread): in function [`do_wait`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/ident/do_wait).

Same search, `do_wait` is used by some drivers and by [`wait4`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/exit.c#L1705) and [`waitid`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/exit.c#L1646)system calls, and by some drivers.